# Excel Workbook opens as Read-Only because Connection Files

Tags: excel, vba, connection, readonly

I have an group of 3 interconnected workbooks that pull data from each other. The way I have it pulling data is through Connections. All files are located in the same drive. What I am trying to do is to open all three files at the same time to make edits. However, once I open workbook "A", I can not properly open files "B" or "C" as it displays that the file is in use by another user and only gives the option to open as Read-Only.

Is there a work around to open all files at the same time in Write mode? I have tried including a ChangeFileAccess to Read but that does not work.

Thanks!

---

UPDATE:

I linked all files using Data > Connections. To further expand, these files open as UserForms on startup and I have added this code under "ThisWorkbook" to do that (open the UserForm automatically and hide the workbook). I am beginning to think that my problem of not being able to open more than one of this documents at the same time is because of this piece of code, but I am not sure what it might be or if there's a better way to open Userform & hide workbook. Any advice is appreciated. Below is the code I have under "ThisWorkbook":

```js
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'important to reset this
    Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = False
    
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'need to use ontime to allow xl to initialise fully
    Application.OnTime Now, "ThisWorkbook.OnlyOneOfMe"

End Sub


Private Sub OnlyOneOfMe()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    On Error GoTo BAD
    With Application
        If Me.ReadOnly Or .Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
            Me.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
            Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
            xlApp.Visible = True
            xlApp.Workbooks.Open (Me.FullName)
            GoTo BAD
        Else
            'stop opening from explorer (but not from excel)
            .Visible = False
            .IgnoreRemoteRequests = True
            UserForm1.Show
            .Visible = True
            '.Quit
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End With
BAD: If Err Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "ERROR"
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Me.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Does someone have the other two files open? You can have multiple excel files open in write mode without issues ordinarily.

Comment: @Warcupine No one has the other files open, I myself was trying to open all three at the same time, but after I opened the first one and in attempting to open the other two - I only received the Read-Only option for the latter two files.

Comment: I can't recreate the issue. Linking one file to another using: data tab --> New Query -->from file works for me with both in modify mode, so I don't think the issue is with connections.

Comment: You might have them stuck open in a hidden window, that happens to me sometimes. Open the task manager and delete all the open excel processes that might fix it.

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem, can you describe how you linked the files?